# Samba share mounts have wrong permissions

Tags: server, mount, permissions, samba

In my `/etc/fstab` I have multiple lines similar to

```
//myserver/myshare /media/Server/myshare cifs credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

However I can't access all the shares. Investigating the problem I found that the folders where the shares are mounted have weird ownerships. Most of them are owned by the user root and the group root. One of them is owned by my user but then there are strange ones. One has `speech-dispatcher` as the owner and `utempter` as the group. Then there's one that's owned by the group `1005` and one that's owned by `www-data` group.

These shares are served from a Ubuntu server and I believe these groups and owners come from there. The ones that I said have `root:root` owner are currently disconnected from the server. The one that is owned by me is a personal home folder share. Could it be that the server tells my machine the ids of the shares and because they don't map one to one on my machine and the server they are seen as these strange groups and users? And since my computer doesn't have a group with id 1005 it shows as just the number in `ls -la`?

How do I fix this? I want all the mounts to be owned by my own user.

I tried dismounting the shares and changing the share folders' ownership with `chown`. This worked partly: Now I can access the share that had `root:1005` owner, but the ones with a group or user id which is found locally too don't work.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the user and group when you configure the fstab mount for the share if you want to control the user (uid) or group (uid). Maybe something like this:

```
//myserver/myshare /media/Server/myshare cifs uid=1000, gid=100, credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Note that the ***uid is set for the first user (1000)*** (You I suppose) and the ***gid is set for user-group named users (gid=100)***

The man page for all the options is

```
man mount.cifs
```

Comment: You may have to add the `forceuid` option since `uid=` only applies if the server does not provide an owner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the only one who access these shares on your server? If yes, can you change it on your server?
What happen if you access the files via nautilius and standar gvfs instead of cifs-mount?

I usaly create the folders unter /mnt and give my user or the groupe users with chown rights to it and than mount it.

for example to change the groupe of a folder you can

```
sudo chown :users /path/to/your/folder
```

Regards

Comment: In Nautilus selecting `Connect to server` works on every share. Chowning the mount folders doesn't work as it changed them back.